# wxPython Mouse Entering/Leaving event methods don't work on Linux

Tags: events, wxpython, mouse, bind

I am trying to provide a custom button class that needs a hover for it to work properly.  I am therefore using StaticBitmap and extending it.  But I am finding differences between Windows and Linux using the same exact code between both.  The following small simple example doesn't work properly in Linux, but works fine in Windows:

```
import wx
class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Test")
        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(200,100))
        panel.SetBackgroundColour("Black")

        # create a normal bitmap button
        bitmap = wx.Bitmap("images/power.png", wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        self.image1 = wx.StaticBitmap(panel, bitmap=bitmap, size=bitmap.GetSize())
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.image1)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)

        # This works on Windows, but not on Linux
        #self.image1.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnHover)
        #self.image1.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnLeaveHover)

        # This (used by itself) gets events for both Linux/Win, but 
        # doesn't find e.Entering() or e.Leaving() on Linux!
        self.image1.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSE_EVENTS, self.OnMouseEvents)

    def OnHover(self, e):
        print "Hover"

    def OnLeaveHover(self,e):
        print "Leaving Hover"

    def OnMouseEvents(self,e):
        print "Mouse event"
        #print dir(e)
        if e.Entering():
            print "Hover"
        elif e.Leaving():
            print "Leaving Hover"
        else:
            e.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyForm()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Is this a known issue?  Is there some other way to bind the event to get the mouseover/hover operation to work properly in Linux?

Also, no forms of `self.Bind()` work here on Linux or Windows.  Why?  i.e.:

```
self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnHover, self.image1)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnLeaveHover, self.image1)
```

Comment: The second question about self.Bind() not working for either Linux or Windows is explained in "wxPython in Action" book.  Enter/Leaving events cannot be bound to the frame.  So scratch that.  The bigger question is why Entering()/Leaving() is not working on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm..., all I can tell you is what I experienced with your code when using it in Ubuntu 12.04

1) My picture never shows up (i.e. a grey window nothing more)

2) when binding the EVT_ENTER/LEAVE_WINDOW to self and not to image1 (see below), it works

```
# This now works on Linux
    #self.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnHover)
    #self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnLeaveHover)
```

I hope this helps you in some form. Also I would like to add that I have made many a bad experience with cross-platform compatibility of wxpython unfortunately. I like the library a lot, but once it delves into more obscure widgets, the behaviour may differ wildly between Windows and Linux.

I remember trying to use the MPlayerCtrl once and for the same method in Windows it would return 0 while in Linux it would return -1 (can't mind exactly which method it was, that project got dumped once I noticed it)

Maybe, this is another one of those strange behaviours...

---

Having thought about it some more.

instead of binding the event to the picture, you could bind it to the widget it is displayed in, such as your panel.

```
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY, size=(200,100))
    self.panel.SetBackgroundColour("Black")

    ...

    #self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnHover)
    #self.pane.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnLeaveHover)
```

Comment: Well, changing to bind to the panel or frame makes the event fire as soon as the mouse enters those, but what I am looking for it an event to fire when the mouse enters the image.

Comment: If you left wxPython, where did you go?  I'm looking for a proven open source cross-platform GUI.  Thanks.

Comment: @David Lynch: Sorry for the late reply. FWIW, check this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415727/how-to-create-hover-effect-on-staticbitmap-in-wxpython  it seems to be a bug that "still" isn't fixed.

Comment: @David Lynch: Regarding your second question. I haven't done much GUI stuff lately. I tried my hand at GTK+3, but I think that is only for Linux at the moment (not sure).
There are, of course, the usual suspects like PyQt, pyGTK, Tkinter etc ( http://docs.python.org/2/faq/gui ). People have recommended PyQt, but I can't comment and since there is a company behind it, licence may be an issue. I honestly have not found a satisfactory answer, myself. It seems to always be a trade-off whatever you do. Sorry, that I can't give you a more concrete answer. Just go for one and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

you should bind the **wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW/wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW** event to **self.panel**. that works.

**wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW/wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW** is **not** the subclass of wx.CommandEvent class. It isn't thrown up to the parent window to process.